# Xpath getting divs and h3 between them

Tags: xpath

Suppose the following structure

```
<div>Content 1</div>
<h3>head 2</h3>
<div>Content 2</div>
<h3>head 3</h3>
<div>Content 3</div>
```

I need to access all divs and the h3 following each of them.

I tried `//div[*]` but it just only returns divs without h3. I need to know something like concatenation or something like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible ways, using XPath union (`|`) :

```
//div | //h3
```

Or matching by `name()` :

```
//*[name()='div' or name()='h3']
```